# the interface to make the content of the web page viewable in all types of browsers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am going to take Microsoft 70-486 (MVC) exam. So i am preparing for it. Came across one most important question asking in 70-486 exam but the answer is different across web, Please help to choose the correct answer.

**Question**

You are designing an HTML5 website. You need to design the interface to make the content of the web page viewable in all types of browsers, including voice recognition software, screen readers, and reading pens. What should you do?

- Annotate HTML5 content elements with Accessible Rich Internet
  Application (ARIA) attributes.
- Convert HTML5 forms to XForms.
- Ensure that HTML5 content elements
  have valid and descriptive names.
- Use HTML5 semantic markup elements
  to enhance the pages.
- Use Resource Description Framework (RDF) to
  describe content elements throughout the entire page.

In some website it is mentioned as AD is correct answer check this [enter link description here](http://www.examskey.com/demopdf/70-486.pdf) and others mentioned ABCD is correct answer check this [enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B88_6d1RUOE2WDkwTTZiYTBzOWs/edit?pli=1). I am confused between this 2 ans.

Answer (score 10):

I would say that the correct answers are :

- [Annotate HTML5 content elements with Accessible Rich Internet Application (ARIA) attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessible_Rich_Internet_Applications) : It is the primary role of the aria attributes !
- Use HTML5 semantic markup elements to enhance the pages : To help the screen readers to know that an element is a nav, an article...
- [Ensure that HTML5 content elements have valid and descriptive names](http://accessibility.psu.edu/forms) : i.e. to help the screen readers to know that an input is the "FirstName", and not just a "Text input", a better approach is to use a label for the inputs, but after reading [this article](http://accessibility.psu.edu/forms), it seems that only few screen readers manage the label element.

Comment: I agree that this is the answer.

Comment: Why you think that HTML5 marup can help you with accessible? Do you know about W3C WAI?

Comment: An example with the "aside" element, from the W3C WAI wiki: https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_the_aside_element_to_indicate_tangentially_related_content
"...  the HTML5 aside element to indicate that it's content is tangentially related to the main article or a parent section ..." and then its usage from "...  assistive technologies such as screen readers provide keystrokes to move to the next landmark or region on a page and this includes moving to the aside element ..."

Answer (score 6):

I'm gonna correct Djoul6's answer a bit.

> Ensure that HTML5 content elements have valid and descriptive names.

This is not a correct answer. the name attribute can be whatever, screen readers do not read the name attribute out loud. From the source Djoul6 refered to there was this description. http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/ensure-compat-rsv.html#namedef

> name
>
> text by which software can identify a component within Web
>   content to the user
>
> Note 1: The name may be hidden and only exposed by
>   assistive technology, whereas a label is presented to all users. In
>   many (but not all) cases, the label and the name are the same.
>
> **Note 2: This is unrelated to the name attribute in HTML.**

The correct answer should be

1. Annotate HTML5 content elements with Accessible Rich Internet Application (ARIA) attributes.
2. Use HTML5 semantic markup elements to enhance the pages.

Comment: It seemed strange for me too, but in my link you can see that "[...] Because some screen readers may not implement LABEL, be sure to use other strategies for logical form layout [...] If non-text content is a control or accepts user input, then it has a name that describes its purpose." And then it's the reason why, I think, the answer "content elements have valid and descriptive names" is also valid.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Djoul6, I really have to double check this one. If you are correct I'll delete this answer!

Answer (score 4):

So, correct answers:

- Annotate HTML5 content elements with Accessible Rich Internet
  Application (ARIA) attributes.
- Use Resource Description Framework (RDF) to describe content elements
  throughout the entire page.

Please note that the correct answer should be a **complete solution** for Accessible web application. HTML5 semantic markup cannot be complete solution, this only enhance the pages, also XForms cannot, and even not valid and descriptive names..

I think no question about ARIA attributes, but you can read about RDF - https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles

For futher investigation please reffer [W3C WAI-ARIA](https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of HTML5 is that its semantic markup is meant to make it readable across browsers and readers. That would point to the 4th answer.